# Parse date and time with time zone in JavaScript/jQuery from YYYY-DD-MM HH:MM:SS UTC--3 format

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime, timezone

I want to parse date in format `YYYY-DD-MM HH:MM:SS UTC--3` format or `YYYY-DD-MM HH:MM:SS UTC+9` format and perform some processing later (like calculating difference in days, hours and minutes from current date, converting the parse date to some other time zone).

Are there any functions available in JavaScript/jQuery?

### Edit

To clarify, I am asking for *timezone* parsing. Also I am not asking about any library reference. I was asking this for how to do it in pure JS or jQuery. So this question is not off-topic.

Comment: Simplest is use a library like [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: This is a duplicate of many, many other questions. The only difference is that in most of the others, the authors wrote some code whereas you're just asking for someone to write it for you.

Comment: @RobG When I didn't find a feasible way to parse timezone in plain js, what's the point of posting useless code in question, just to avoid comments like you just did? And before marking a question as duplicate, you must verify if the answers there solve my question. Even the questions are not the same and it's nowhere duplicate to my question.

Comment: Parsing the timezone component is not difficult as shown in answers to [various questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+parse+with+timezone). Yes, you should post as much as you can write, parsing the timezone part is just 2 or 3 lines of code. Check the deleted answers.

Comment: Sorry, I checked the questions in the link you provided in the comment and top 20 questions were different than mine (Though some of them had the same answer as here- to use moment js). Parsing Timezone in ISO8601 format may be 2-3 lines of code but my format is a bit different and I do not want to convert between formats. If possible, can you provide a link to how this can be done in pure JS? as I am still interested in a pure JS/jquery method to do this (except to manually extract the offset and add/subtract it from parsed time). I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @KashyapKotak—check the deleted answers here. Answers of "use library X" don't count as answers, they should be comments. If the accepted answer here was really the best answer, then this question is a duplicate of every question that was ever answered by "use moment.js", and every question about dates is similarly a duplicate. The accepted answer doesn't even show how to parse your format with the suggested library.

Comment: "how to parse your format" becomes very obvious when you click on the link in answer. This answer at least guides me in a direction to solve my question instead of just not answering and leaving me wasting my time trying for ways that do not work.

Comment: Still if you feel that what you know may be a better answer, Please post it so that all the "duplicate" answers you mentioned will have a valid answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For time and date manipulation there are usefull libraries

## Momentjs

https://momentjs.com/

You can easily parse date with

`var day = moment("YYYY-DD-MM HH:MM:SS");`  and manipulate with it with https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/ also when you are processing timezone please take a look to https://momentjs.com/timezone/ I used it on large production app with calculating difference in hours between zones and it works like a charm

## Date-fns

If you need simpler manipulation and smaller code size please take a look to this https://date-fns.org/ My colleague did it and we are using it on site with ~1M monthly users. It's super fast and provides you basic function for date manipulations like (adding days, seconds, or perfect helpers needed for date calculations) but currently it lacks timezone support so choice is yours. Have a nice day and be brave while working with dates in JavaScript :) It's painful and stressful road in JavaScript

Comment: I'll go with moment.js for Timezone support. Thanks.

Comment: Answers of "use library X" are not answers, they should be comments. There is no need for moment.js timezone for parsing as the offset is provided in the OP string. You should at least show how to parse the string using one of the suggested libraries.